# Does ROS Tango work?

Tags: java, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's been a couple years and I have come back to see if ROS Tango works.  Unfortunately, the [tutorials](https://github.com/ologic/Tango/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Tango-and-ROS) fail miserably, requiring old versions of everything from Android Studio 0.6 to unsupported gradle versions and plugins. Even with those it generates run-time errors.

The tutorials page has not been updated since September, 2014, so I think it is an abandoned project.  That's too bad, as it would be a useful thing to have working.  Does anyone have a Tango that has a ROS interface?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251079/does-ros-tango-work?/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2017-01-01

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-02**:
This is a bit of a 'me too' comment, but I've not seen any development in that direction either. It's definitely a shame, as Tango devices are very interesting. I'd be interested to see whether you get any more informative responses, especially since the OSRF worked on Tango with Google.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-02**:
See [OSRF Blog - Project Tango Announced](http://www.osrfoundation.org/project-tango-announced/) fi.

**Comment by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on 2017-01-03**:
I remember i was able to send my pointcloud and position over wifi using the yellowstone tablet. I could not merge the RGB data with the pointcloud though. If this is what you are looking for I could search what tutorials I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look around here: http://wiki.ros.org/tango_ros_streamer.

That is an Android application that will publish Tango data to ROS topics. The core of that application is a ROSJava node that you can integrate into another application (http://wiki.ros.org/tango_ros_streamer/tango_ros_node).

The code of the application is open source, and you can install it into your Tango enabled device from the Play store for free.

A bit late, but hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2018-01-27**:
That works, but not for the orginal Tango development kit.  For an explanation of why it fails for that, see this link:
https://github.com/Intermodalics/tango_ros/issues/384

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2018-01-29**:
@dan previous releases of the application used to work with the development kit; I've used them myself. Don't expect them to be feature-complete nor completely bug-free, but they work.
Take a look here: https://github.com/Intermodalics/tango_ros/releases, download the apk and install it with adb.

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2018-02-27**:
@jubeira Great call!  It works with this version of tango_ros_streamer:
https://github.com/Intermodalics/tango_ros/releases/tag/v1.0-15

See this thread for more details:
https://github.com/Intermodalics/tango_ros/issues/384